# How to add .bsh script file to BeanShell Assertion Externally

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I just need to know what **function** is used to add the script file in BeanShell Assertion.

[image: Link to the Image]

Ex: Like if we need to add a file to HTTP Request we can use `__FileToString` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got it**
In the *Scriptfile* area just add the ***relative path*** of your file.

**NOTE:** No need to write any function here.